# what kernel structures are mapped in each process image?

Tags: kernel, ram, process

I know that for every process image there is a part reserved for the kernel. But what structures are in there exactly? Can someone give me an exhaustive list? Thanks!

This is an image of what I am referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511982/virtual-address-space-in-the-context-of-programming

Comment: Kernel reserved memory is separate from and off limits to system and userspace processes … It is strictly managed by the kernel and only processes that relate to kernel's subsystems can utilize it … This is not mixed with or reliant on external processes allocated memory in any way if that’s what you’re asking about.

Comment: yes that was my question, thank you! So the kernel memory shown in this graphic is not copied for every process image. It is kernel-reserved memory and contains all the kernel space structures like IDT, GDT, drivers, a task manager and a file system right?

Comment: Correct, in that it is not copied to external processes' space … Those processes don’t even have direct access to kernel’s reserved memory space nor to its contents unless the kernel decides so … The kernel on the other hand has full access to those processes memory space … As for the contents of the kernel’s reserved memory, those are mostly essential OS parts that need to be loaded at all times but some can be loaded/unloaded as needed … Therefore, pages in the kernel’s reserved memory space are not swapable and are even excluded from usual memory management routines like LRU lists etc.

Comment: … assuming we’re talking about the Linux kernel … Although other OSs kernels are generally mostly similar in how they reserve and manage reserved kernel memory AFAIK. but it’s better to refer to those OSs documentation for differences.